# Remove a specified file during the installation in wix

Tags: file, wix, installation

I am facing the below issue, from my product setup we are mainitaining one license file. for every product setup we are updating the license file with the latest one. when my new setup trying to replace the older license file, the licenfile is truncated and gone the file size from 3 kb to 1 kb. 
So fixing this issue, i need to delete the existing license file and need to copy the new license file in the same path.

Please help me to remove the single file during the wix installation, I am using the below code,

code:

please let me know your thoughts using this way of proceedings......

Thanks ,
Santhosh

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [RemoveFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_removefile.htm) element

Comment: HI ,I used the remove file element. It is not working when i try to install my setup into a server location. It caused the same problem that is the license file is again trucating. <RemoveFile Id="lic_lice_remove" Name="lic*.lic" On="install" />

Answer (score -1):

You can use Custom Action that will check and delete file before Installation starts custom action

Comment: HI ,I used the remove file element. It is not working when i try to install my setup into a server location. It caused the same problem that is the license file is again trucating. <RemoveFile Id="lic_lice_remove" Name="lic*.lic" On="install" />. Please let me know how to use the custom actions in wix

Comment: In My answer is was talking about C# custom action that can be run during installation. Check this site for more info:[http://blog.torresdal.net/CommentView,guid,FE27427F-FF4F-4056-BC50-C98E23227C6D.aspx]